# What's the difference between three etcd-go package?

Tags: go, package, etcd

There are three different etcd-go package, they are:

1. [github.com/coreos/etcd](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/coreos/etcd/clientv3?tab=doc)
2. [go.etcd.io/etcd](https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3?tab=doc)
3. [go.etcd.io/etcd/v3](https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/v3/clientv3?tab=doc)

According to the commit [here](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/commit/96cce208c2cb9e70ac3573b3f76eed7c84d262d1), all the
official codes have changed the package from `go.etcd.io/etcd` to `go.etcd.io/etcd/v3` with following messages:

> This change makes the etcd package compatible with the existing Go
> ecosystem for module versioning.

But I can't get the `go.etcd.io/etcd/v3` package by `go get` command.

So what's the difference between these three etcd-go packages? And how to use them properly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no much difference in both packages as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue in the client `v3.4` with `go get` failing. See this issue: https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/issues/11154

Although the issue has been closed because it is (supposedly) fixed in `v3.5`, that version is not yet released (when writing this).

There are a few workarounds posted the issue above. The one that worked for us was to circumvent the incorrectly implemented go module of `etcd` and pin the version to a commit directly in our go.mod file:

```
require go.etcd.io/etcd v0.0.0-20200520232829-54ba9589114f
```

The `clientv3` is then imported with:

```golang
import "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3"
```

Answer (score 0):

The document for no.2 in the question points to this link

> https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3?tab=doc

The package has below version and commit hash

> v0.5.0 (ae9734e)

The document for no.3 in the question points to this link

> https://pkg.go.dev/go.etcd.io/etcd/v3/clientv3?tab=doc

The package has below version and commit hash

> v3.3.0 (c20cc05)

etcd would have made a breaking change in latest release and hence changed the module path to differ from the old path. This is a convention recommended in official Golang blog.

Read this blog.
https://blog.golang.org/v2-go-modules
Even though both of them point to the same repo, you have to import these versions differently like below. You can find the correct module path from go.mod file in the root of the repository.

> import "go.etcd.io/etcd/clientv3"

> import "go.etcd.io/etcd/v3/clientv3"

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the `go.etcd.io/etcd/v3/clientv3` package not work for me. And `go get go.etcd.io/etcd/v3` will return `module go.etcd.io/etcd@upgrade found (v3.3.25+incompatible), but does not contain package go.etcd.io/etcd/v3`.

Comment: @Alexander The version referred in the question is v3.3.0 To get the version, you can use this command by mentioning the commit hash related to the version "go get go.etcd.io/etcd/v3/clientv3@c20cc05" Go install should work fine after this.